# Compiler optimizations of inlined functions in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, inlining

When a function which take a pointer in argument is inlined, does the compiler remove the indirection during the optimization process ? Of course when it makes sense..

Here is an obvious example:

```
inline void say_hello (person* p) {
    std::cout << "hello " << p->name << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    person goldorak;
    goldorak.name = "Goldorak";

    say_hello(&goldorak);
    return 0;
}
```

This case is trivial but if the compiler does the optimization is there some cases in which it doesn't ?

**Bonus**: where can I get a list of some "basic" optimizations made by my compiler ?

Ps: I'm just curious

Comment: Why not compare the assembly yourself?

Comment: You ask 'where can I get a list of some "basic" optimizations made by my compiler ?' without saying what your compiler is.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: because I'm not comfortable with assembly

Comment: @Simon: If you're not comfortable with the compilation target, what sort of answer would you expect that would be useful to you? Optimizations usually only manifest in the resulting target code...

Comment: @Julian: I'm pretty sure almost all good compilers are doing approximately the same optimizations. At least in simple cases like this (I'm using clang & gcc)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: sort of those below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming GCC,
and so the link you are looking for is http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

And to quote: (this may not be what you were getting at)

> -findirect-inlining
>       Inline also indirect calls that are discovered to be known at
>   compile time thanks to previous inlining. This option has any effect
>   only when inlining itself is turned on by the -finline-functions or
>   -finline-small-functions options.
>
> ```
> Enabled at level -O2.
> ```

The equivilent documentation for Visual Studio compilers (including C++)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx
(you can follow the links for more info)

Answer (score 1):

A good compiler would do this. It would be a two-stage process, though. First it would inline the function. A later phase could then realize that the only use of the struct is to temporarily hold `name` and eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in my experience this is true for both pointers (C and C++) and references (C++ only of course) - pretty much any decent compiler will optimise away redundant indirection. Even Visual Studio does this.